# Wordpress plugin - not working javascript function in onclick

Tags: wordpress

I am working in wordpress plugin. I need to work with some javascript functions. So that I have followed below steps.

This is my constructor function

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
        $this->includes();
        $this->initHooks();
}
```

I have included some hooks in initHooks function

```
public function includes() {
    include sprintf( '%s/includes/package.php', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
    include sprintf( '%s/includes/booking.php', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
}
```

This is my include function

```
public function initHooks() {
        add_action("admin_enqueue_scripts", array($this, "enqueScripts"));
        add_action("admin_menu", array($this, "adminMenuPages"));
        add_filter("plugin_action_links_$this->plugin", array($this, "settingsLink"));
}
```

This is my hooks function

```
public function enqueScripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style('az-styles', plugins_url("/assets/css/style.css", __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('az-scripts', plugins_url("/assets/js/lib/jquery-3.6.0.min.js", __FILE__), array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('az-scripts', plugins_url("/assets/js/app.js", __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    }
}
```

This is my script section and javascript was loaded successfully

```
function clickHandler() {
    var name = jQuery("#name").value()
    if(name == "") {
        alert("The name field is required")
    }
}
```

This is my javascript function

I am using this function in package.php file

```
// Output the field
        echo '<input type="text" id="name" onclick="clickHandler()" name="location" value="' . esc_textarea( $location )  . '" class="widefat">';
        echo '<input type="text" name="phone" value="' . esc_textarea( $phone )  . '" class="widefat">';
        echo '<input type="text" name="email" value="' . esc_textarea( $email )  . '" class="widefat">';
        echo '<input type="text" name="description" value="' . esc_textarea( $description )  . '" class="widefat">';
        echo '<input type="text" name="address" value="' . esc_textarea( $address )  . '" class="widefat">';
```

But I am getting the below error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: clickHandler is not defined
```

Could someone let me know what I missed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Press CTRL+U check your js file is added in source?

Comment: styles file was included but js files not

Comment: Error was clickHandler function is not found so please enqueue script first

Comment: public function enqueScripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style('az-styles', plugins_url("/assets/css/style.css", __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('az-scripts', plugins_url("/assets/js/lib/jquery-3.6.0.min.js", __FILE__), array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('az-scripts', plugins_url("/assets/js/app.js", __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    }
}
Already I have added this